# "Debug is not enabled in the current configuration" - how to enable it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When trying to debug a Release build of a Xamarin.Forms app on iOS from Visual Studio on a PC, I get the following message:

[image]

But the "iOS Build" screen doesn't have any option for that. So how can I test a Release build on an iOS device?

Comment: Assuming you are looking for an "ad hoc" deployment to a physical device  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ad-hoc-distribution?tabs=macos

Comment: @SushiHangover No. I'm trying to overcome a different bug that only occurs in Release - the app published fine to the app store for beta testing, but would simply crash. Now (perhaps because of a VS update) I sometimes get an error that it can't find a provisional profile for signing. The bottom line is that I just want to run the app for testing on the phone, but in Release mode.

Comment: @SushiHangover It actually publishes to the phone sometimes, but when I start it, it crashes immediately. So I want to debug it and see what happens.

Comment: on VS Mac under iOS project options there is a "iOS Debug" tab

Comment: @Jason I'm doing this on a PC (connected to a Mac).

Comment: logon to the Mac and build directly from there - I assume the same debug option is available on the PC but just hidden away somewhere

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When selecting **Release** mode for Xamarin iOS project, you need to **Enable debugging** .

Follow this steps : ***iOS properties -> iOS Debug - > Enable debugging***

[image]